# Downloading multiple fasta files from ncbi

Tags: ftp, wget, fasta, ncbi

I'm trying to download all fasta files associated with one organism from ncbi.

I tried `wget -r -l3 -A "*.fna.gz" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/Microcystis_aeruginosa/` to get all files ending in .fna.gz from the third level down, but then it just rejects everything with the following output:

Removed “ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/Microcystis_aeruginosa/latest_assembly_versions/.listing”.
Rejecting “GCF_000010625.1_ASM1062v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000307995.1_ASM30799v2”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312165.1_ASM31216v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312185.1_ASM31218v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312205.1_ASM31220v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312225.1_ASM31222v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312245.1_ASM31224v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312265.1_ASM31226v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312285.1_ASM31228v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000312725.1_ASM31272v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000330925.1_MicAerT1.0”.
Rejecting “GCF_000332585.1_MicAerD1.0”.
Rejecting “GCF_000412595.1_spc777-v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000599945.1_Mic70051.0”.
Rejecting “GCF_000787675.1_ASM78767v1”.
Rejecting “GCF_000981785.1_ASM98178v1”.

Any ideas on why it's rejecting these directories? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm thinking you are requesting too much too frequently on their server so they kicked you out. You should really write a shell script that sleeps inbetween each wget so you don't overload the server.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it's rejecting your request, but when I was still doing this type of thing, I found that if I don't download queries in smaller batches, the NCBI server timed me out and blocked my IP for a while before I could download again. This doesn't seem to be the same problem that your seeing, but maybe this script might get the same thing done. Let me know if this helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Bio import Entrez

search_term = raw_input("Organism name: ")

Entrez.email = "your_email@isp.com"   # required by NCBI
search_handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term=search_term, usehistory="y")
search_results = Entrez.read(search_handle)
search_handle.close()

gi_list = search_results["IdList"]
count = int(search_results["Count"])
webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
query_key = search_results["QueryKey"]

batch_size = 5    # download sequences in batches so NCBI doesn't time you out

with open("ALL_SEQ.fasta", "w") as out_handle:
    for start in range(0, count, batch_size):
        end = min(count, start+batch_size)
        print "Going to download record %i to %i" % (start+1, end)
        fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", retmode="text",retstart=start, retmax=batch_size, webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key)
        data = fetch_handle.read()
        fetch_handle.close()
        out_handle.write(data)

print ("\nDownload completed")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, that code still seemed to overload their server. But i'm actually trying to pull off whole genomes using the genome db rather than the nucleotide db. I think this requires the use of elink to link the id's in the genome db with the id's in the nucleotide db, which is where the data is actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

I found a perl script that gets me close to accomplishing this task from [here](http://ncbiinsights.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2013/02/19/how-to-download-bacterial-genomes-using-the-entrez-api/#more-141) . Unfortunately, this script is just returning the ID's of the genomes, and not the actual sequences.

For example, the head of my output is:

> gi|425458296|ref|NZ_CAIN00000000.1|NZ_CAIN01000000 Microcystis aeruginosa PCC 9808, whole genome shotgun sequencing project
>
> gi|425448636|ref|NZ_CAIK00000000.1|NZ_CAIK01000000 Microcystis aeruginosa PCC 7941, whole genome shotgun sequencing project

Any perl users know what's going on?

```
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
my ($name, $outname, $url, $xml, $out, $count, $query_key, $webenv, $ids);
my @genomeId;
my $base = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/';
my $limit = 'wgs[prop]+AND+srcdb+refseq[prop])';
my @species = ('Microcystis aeruginosa');

foreach my $s (@species) {
  undef @genomeId;
  $query_key = $webenv = '';
  $s =~ s/ /+/g;

  # ESearch
  $url = $base . "esearch.fcgi?db=genome&term=$s";
  $xml = get($url);
  $count = $1 if ($xml =~ /<Count>(\d+)<\/Count>/);

  if ($count > 30) {
    $url = $base . "esearch.fcgi?db=genome&term=$s&retmax=$count";
    $xml = get($url);
  }

  while ($xml =~ /<Id>(\d+?)<\/Id>/gs) {
    push(@genomeId, $1);
  }

  $ids = join(',', @genomeId);

  # ELink
  $url = $base . "elink.fcgidbfrom=genome&db=nuccore&cmd=neighbor_history&id=$ids&term=$limit";
  $xml = get($url);
  $query_key = $1 if ($xml =~ /<QueryKey>(\d+)<\/QueryKey>/);
  $webenv = $1 if ($xml =~ /<WebEnv>(\S+)<\/WebEnv>/);

  # EFetch
  $url = $base . "efetch.fcgidb=nuccore&query_key=$query_key&WebEnv=$webenv&rettype=fasta&retmode=text";
  $out = get($url);

  open (OUT, ">$s.fna");
  close OUT; 
}
```